# Patch SUPEE-5994 broken Varien_Autoload

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, fatal-error, varien-autoload

I have been going through all patches and applying them in order of oldest to recent, where relevant in regards to **1.7.0.2**.

I could not apply **SUPEE-5994** as the shell triggered numerous errors (*I cannot replicate these errors.*)

Whilst attempting to apply this patch I was doing so via SSH as the user whom is the owner of the virtual host whilst inside their *Document Root* `public_html` (*I was **not** the root user*)

Using another article I downloaded the contents of the patch and manually applied them.

When I run the patch shell `./PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh` I receive the following output:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php.rej
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php.rej
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 184 with fuzz 2 (offset 22 lines).
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/messages.phtml.rej
patching file get.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file get.php.rej
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
42 out of 42 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php.rej
The next patch would create the file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Io/File.php.rej
```

This clearly suggest that the manual patch files I have applied work correctly as intended.  However **ultimately, the problem prompting this question** - This has caused the `Varien_Autoload` to fail to find a class that literally exists.

I have:

- NOT got the compiler turned on;
- NOT got the cache turned on;
- Cleared the compiler anyway;
- Cleared the cache anyway;
- Changed the `Varien/Autoload.php` temporarily to `require` instead of `include`

I then get the following error:

> Fatal error: Varien_Autoload::autoload(): Failed opening required 'Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php'
>       (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:app/code/core:lib:.:') in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 96

I can confirm the following file **DOES** exist:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
```

How do I move forward from this point?

Comment: Its strange that your include paths are relative instead absolute. Can you try making a PHP file in the root magento install directory with this; <?php include("app/Mage.php"); echo BP;

Comment: Did you confirm there were no core code changes for your Magento version before starting to apply security patches?

Comment: @user3661841 The paths were edits by 7ochem - I presume so it's more indexable in google and would be more helpful to others.

Comment: @JonathanHussey There are no core modifications.

Comment: Are your permissions correct?

Comment: @JonathanHussey Permissions are correct. (this was one of the first things i checked - *as previously incorrect permissions has been a problem to previous patches*)

Comment: Ok well you are saying the file exists and the permissions are correct, but the update script is saying this is not the case - I would say you need to investigate that further.  Also to ask a stupid question, the patch script is in the right directory location?

Comment: @JonathanHussey I'm running the patch shell inside of the Document Root.  I will also update the thread on your first comment.